# Undo [android-wear] -> [android] tag synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

According to [How can I dispute a tag synonym?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253382/how-can-i-dispute-a-tag-synonym) this is the proper place to ask, "as long as we make a good argument". :)

Not too long ago (I didn't notice when) [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) seems to have been marked as a synonym of [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). I think this is mistaken, for the following reasons:

1. [Android Wear](https://developer.android.com/wear/index.html) is a distinct product, for a separate platform, unlike [android-tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablet) or [android-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-device) which are correct synonyms in my opinion.

   - The difference would be, say, approximately the same as between [windows-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) and [windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8).
   - Also, if [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) is a synonym, [google-glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-glass) would be too, in my opinion.
2. Although some Android Wear questions may actually be Android questions, the tag had been "correctly" used (in my opinion) in that [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) questions were actually specific to Wear (notifications, wear-specific UI, watch faces, handheld-watch communication, &c). Also, this "inclusion" argument may also apply to, say, [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).
3. This tag would seem to warrant specific subscription (at least I was subscribed to it).

If possible, could this be reversed?

Comment: Looking at the [meta-tag:synonym-request] info-page, you are asking for moderator-help and thus should tag this [meta-tag:support].

Comment: I removed the synonym. Waiting on cache update to see what kind of damage was done...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm glad you caught this. This is a clear case where one tag is a subset of the other, but those terms are *not* synonymous. Luckily you noticed it before the tags were merged, so after removing the synonym there are 511 questions tagged [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear). The synonym had only been converted 11 times when it was in effect, so the damage was minimal.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And thank you for fixing it so quickly!

Comment: The synonym is back, see [Undo the \[android-wear\] -> \[android\] tag synonym again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289310)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. I deleted it again.