# Undo the [android-wear] -> [android] tag synonym again

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

I think this happened before and now it happened again. When I click my saved [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) it takes me to [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions. Could we revert this once again?

The rationale is that I am comfortable answering [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) questions and would like to look only for them. If I get redirected to [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions, I can't easily find questions to answer.

Link to the previous meta post: [Undo [android-wear] -> [android] tag synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276120/undo-android-wear-android-tag-synonym/276141#276141).

Comment: The proposed synonyms for [tag:android] aren't good either...

Comment: who ever approved this should be more careful in the future!

Comment: @hichris123: Well, they are all from the same <4K user... BTW: Only 1 rename to date.

Comment: Is the api totally different or just an extension of android's?

Comment: @Braiam Extension of Android's, although there are quite a few differences.

Comment: is it possibile to revert it? It is kind of annoying

Comment: It's deleted again. I don't know what makes people think this synonym is a good idea. Thanks for drawing attention to it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Maybe mods need a way to blacklist synonyms? ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator We should be able to blacklist them, and save a custom message that's displayed the next time someone suggests it. :)