# Incorrect tag association for [winbatch]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

There is a tag called [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) -- but clicking it brings up questions tagged [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file).

The two are not remotely the same. WinBatch is an unfortunately-named high level language (similar to AHK) that has been around about as long as... batch files... But completely different. [(Visit their site.)](http://winbatch.com/)

Can this association be broken so that only questions tagged [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) appear with the WinBatch tag?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the right place? Also asking this is how, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253382/3001761

Comment: Created 5 years ago Mar 26 '11 at 9:03. I don't see anything other than this question on a meta search for [winbatch](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=winbatch)

Comment: There likely wouldn't be, as they provide their own forum for questions. However, this forum system is much better. There have been a few WB questions over the years. I would like to keep track of them, if poss.

Comment: Technically - the association *can* be broken - it's a few clicks by a mod. What you need to do is prove why removing the syn. is *better* than the status quo - not only now, but moving forward... If we break them, will things get wrongly tagged, are the community/you willing to re-tag as appropriate etc...

Comment: @JonClements At the moment, the association renders the `WinBatch` tag both inaccurate and unhelpful. `WinBatch` scripts are as different from `batch-files` as `apples` from `appliances` -- despite the shared letters. It would be best to either remove the tag (it is seldom used) or break the association. The tag is occasionally used, but a search reports that only 26 posts include the word `WinBatch`. If that is too few to justify the tag then just ghost it I suppose. Better gone than incorrect.

Comment: As somebody who posts almost exclusively on the [batch-file] tag, I can say that batch and WinBatch are about as similar as Java and Javascript. I wouldn't even know how to answer a WinBatch question.

Answer (score 17):

I think it is amply evident that [WinBatch](http://winbatch.com/) is a completely different topic than batch files, so hopefully it's uncontroversial that *in principle* [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) should be its own, independent tag, not linked to [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) or anything else.

Jon Clements brings up the question of whether breaking the association between [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) and [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) tags would *in practice* do more harm than good, due to improper tagging.

Well, if someone is asking a new batch file question, how likely are they to manually tag their question with [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch)? And if someone is looking for existing batch file questions, how likely are they to search for [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch)? How likely is it that anyone would preferentially choose (or search for) [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) over [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file), [batch-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-files), [bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bat), [.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.bat), [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch), [dos-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos-batch), [windows-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-batch), and [batch-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-script) (which are currently all synonyms)?

My guess is: pretty darn unlikely. Especially so if [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) were to get an appropriate wiki entry (which it can't while synonymized).

From my point of view, there is very little downside to making [winbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winbatch) its own, independent tag.

Regarding the "only 26 posts" (part of a comment on the main question): I am pretty sure I've seen legitimate tags that are more obscure than that. To me, this is not a weak enough showing to warrant killing off the tag completely.