# Undo [d3v4] -> [d3js] tag synonym

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

According to [How can I dispute a tag synonym?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253382/how-can-i-dispute-a-tag-synonym) this is the proper place to ask, "as long as we make a good argument". :)

Quite recently [d3v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3v4) was marked as a synonym of [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js). I think this is a mistake because:

1. The API changes between version 3 and version 4 were **numerous**. Just look at [all the changes!](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

   > D3 4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x. For example, d3.scale.linear is now d3.scaleLinear, and d3.layout.treemap is now d3.treemap. The adoption of ES6 modules also means that D3 is now written exclusively in strict mode and has better readability. And there have been many other significant improvements to D3’s features! (Nearly all of the code from D3 3.x has been rewritten.)

   D3 selections are now immutable, generators like `stack` no longer modify the input data and the general update pattern — perhaps the pattern for which D3 is most well know — changed. The two versions are clearly different.
2. This is inconsistent with every other language and framework on StackOverflow. There's a generic [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and then there are more specific tags like [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). There's a generic [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and then there's a more specific [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2). [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6). [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) and [ruby-on-rails-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) and [ruby-on-rails-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4) and [ruby-on-rails-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-5).

Would it be possible for this synonym to be reversed?

There's also another tag for the version 4 of D3 ([d3.js-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v4)) which is **not** a synonym of [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js). Could [d3.js-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v4) be made a synonym of [d3v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3v4) (or vice versa)?

Comment: Are people answering d3.js questions that different between versions?

Comment: Yes. D3v4 code is not at all compatible with D3v3. Some quick examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897802/code-migration-line-chart-from-d3-v3-to-v4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518438/d3-js-create-stacked-bar-chart-from-values-in-object#comment68295190_40518617 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845121/d3js-v4-where-is-d3-svg-diagonal

Comment: My question was if the users that answered one didn't answer the others.

Answer (score 4):

d3.js version 4.x is still called d3.js, so the tag [d3v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3v4) should never have been made with that name in the first place. At the very least, the tag should be [d3.js-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v4) or [d3.js-4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-4.x)

I'm concerned, though, because as newer versions of d3.js come out (v5, v6, etc.), if they are compatible with v4, then, should we make them synonyms of d3.jsv4? That is just confusing and unnecessary. But we shouldn't make [d3.js-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v5), etc. for each new version. At what point, then, do we switch back over to just using [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)?

In my opinion, the workflow for this should be that users asking d3.js v4 questions should use the [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js) tag and then just mention in their questions that they are using the new, 4th version of d3.js. I see it as the best long term solution, because it will require no system action for when newer versions of d3.js are released, and when d3.js version 3.x and below are unpopular enough that questions stop being asked frequently here, we won't have to go back and change those questions to [d3.js-old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-old) or anything.

Comment: There's a generic [tag:python] and then there are more specific tags like [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x]. There's a generic [tag:angularjs] and then there's a more specific [tag:angularjs-2]. [tag:javascript] and [tag:ecmascript-6]. [tag:ruby-on-rails] and [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] and [tag:ruby-on-rails-4] and [tag:ruby-on-rails-5]. Why should D3 be any different? There are a ton of differences between versions 3 and 4. Just let the users correctly tag their questions!

Comment: @Ashitaka A tag (d3 or otherwise) should be right and sensible regardless of what other tags do. I don't think there should be a RoR tag for each major version, but I was not aware of those before just now, nor am I a RoR programmer. We should avoid unnecessary tag creep; tag naming should follow the skirt convention for writing a paper; broad enough to cover the subject but specific enough to keep it interesting for those trying to search for it, specifically. There's a danger of missing questions if you tag your question only with [tag:d3.js-v4] and I search for only [tag:d3.js].

Comment: @Ashitaka If, today, a d3.js user searches for how to do something in d3.js by using [tag:d3.js] as their tag, could you safely make the assumption they only want to know how to do it in version 3 or older? Could you make the assumption at all? They should see all d3.js questions, and then filter their search further by keywords, such as "v4", which in itself is too broad a term for a tag (obviously), but when paired with the tag [tag:d3.js] should be very effective.