# Merge [d3.js-v5] tag into [d3.js] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I'm active answering questions with the [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js) tag. As already explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338840/5768908), creating a new tag for every new version is advised against. That being said, I have two questions:

1. I just noticed yet another tag, [d3.js-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v5), with a couple of dozen questions. I already [proposed the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/d3.js/synonyms), but since D3 is a quite small community we'll never have 4 votes (my main goal with this question is actually draw attention to that voting). What can we do in that case?
2. D3 v6 was just released 2 weeks ago, and I'm expecting new tags to be created (I'm surprised they weren't yet). Other than removing such new tags manually for every question, what can be done?

Comment: "What can we do in that case?" - synonym request on Meta. Mods can create synonyms without requiring votes, which is useful when communities are too small to deal with synonyms on their own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synonym approved.

Also merged the tags:

[d3v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3v4) to [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)

```
updating post history, 71 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 67 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 4 rows affected
destroying 'd3v4': [d3v4] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 36251
tag remapping of [d3.js] and [d3v4] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
17 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

[d3.js-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v4) to [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)

```
updating post history, 72 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 67 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 9 rows affected
destroying 'd3.js-v4': [d3.js-v4] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 36260
tag remapping of [d3.js] and [d3.js-v4] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
46 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

[d3.js-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-v5) to [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)

```
updating post history, 24 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 23 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
destroying 'd3.js-v5': [d3.js-v5] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 36263
tag remapping of [d3.js] and [d3.js-v5] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```