# It's time to merge [vuejs2] into [vue.js]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

As someone working with Vue on a daily basis, I would say that Vue 2 has become the de facto standard for anyone using this framework. Originally the [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)-tag was meant for Vue 1 but that version has been discontinued nearly five years ago with [version 1.0.28](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue/v/1.0.28) and is no longer supported by the Vue team. That is why its tag has long been used for nothing but Vue 2 questions and has therefore become synonymous with [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2). [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) is also by far the more popular tag (~75k questions vs ~22k questions) for questions about Vue 2.

I'd therefore propose merging [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) into [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) to have a better representation of the current state of Vue. [vuejs3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs3) on the other hand does make a lot of sense and should be kept. What do you think?

The Vue team is doing something similar with their domains: vuejs.org (v2) and v3.vuejs.org (v3). I bet in some distant future where Vue 2 is deprecated, vuejs.org will host Vue 3 just like it happened with Vue 1.

Comment: Do you have any rationalization, other than you think it's a good idea?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I outlined in my post why I think the two tags have grown to become synonyms so I'm not sure where you'd like me to elaborate. It's kind of similar to the [merger of CSS 3 and CSS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385573/make-css3-a-synonym-of-css). There comes a point where version-specific tags stop making sense for some versions.

Comment: There are other tag sets, like the one for C#, that have both types of tags: the master one and version-specific ones.  Can you explain why this tag set should work differently?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know much about C# but with Vue, there isn't Vue and a bunch of versions of it. It's basically one product and if enough breaking changes have accumulated a new version is released. While the version is new it makes sense to differentiate but over time the old version becomes less and less relevant and when 99,9%+ of people are using Vue 2 the need to differentiate from any previous version has ceased to exist. If anything you'd have to create an [vuejs1]-tag bc if you ask a question with the [vue.js] tag today you won't get an answer compatible with Vue 1.

Comment: I agree: I answer D3 questions, which just like Vue is a JS library (or framework, if you want...). We had D3 v2, v3 etc, up to v6. As I claim in [my question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401070/5768908), it makes little sense creating a new tag for each major (semantic versioning) D3 release, as well explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338840/5768908). Thus, I believe that the same reasoning applied for D3 fits Vue as well (which also uses semantic versioning), there should not be a `vue2` (and even a `vue3`) tag.

Comment: Plenty of questions in the vue.js tag predate vue2 - all those are potentially not solving a vue2 specific problem. By merging vuejs2 into vuejs you would lessen the chance of finding something vuejs2 specific question/answer. If people nowadays wrongfully tag their question only with vuejs and not vuejs2 it is a tagging problem. You cannot fix that by throwing all the correctly tagged vuejs2 questions in the bigger bowl of vuejs. The tag description already mentions it: _Vue.js version specific questions should be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3]._

Answer (score 15):

As someone who also contributes to the Vue tags (though is by no means a big name contributor), **I disagree**.

Firstly, to clarify, [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) refers to the library as a whole, not a specific version. Today, there is no version 1 tag, only v2 and v3. It's also worth noting that, while Vue 1, 2, and 3 can run *side-by-side*, they are **not** compatible in the traditional sense. Version-specific syntaxes cannot be intermixed, and unless you're well versed in all major versions it may be hard to know whether your Vue code is "version-specific".

I think the argument you've made that [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) is de facto used for version 2 is a fine one, but I don't think it means we should merge them. Version tags are useful in their own right when referencing something version specific.

For example: at some point, "normal" [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)-tagged posts started using ES5 and ES6 features without labeling such posts specifically with [ecmascript-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5) and [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), but that doesn't necessarily mean those tags should be removed, much less merged with the main JS tag.

The largest objection I have is that [Vue 3 was officially released last September](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/releases/tag/v3.0.0?ref=madewithvuejs.com), and as Vue 3 becomes more popular, the distinction between a post being v2 or v3 will only become *more* important, not less. Merging the v2 tag with the main tag is shooting ourselves in the foot in this regard, especially if Vue 3 ever becomes the de facto version in Stack Overflow questions in the future.

Being able to tag a post with [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) or [vuejs3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs3) or neither is *valuable*, and we would lose this value by merging v2 with the main tag.

As another example, Vue version 1 has many questions on Stack Overflow, but there is no version 1 tag. As a result, all these version 1 questions float aimlessly in the main tag, with no obvious way to find them. Merging [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) to [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) is sentencing Vue 2 questions to the same fate when Vue 3 becomes wide-spread.

Comment: But why would you want to use two tags for the same purpose? Vue 2 and 3 are fundamentally different so I agree that having different tags makes sense rn. However, having both [vue.js] and [vuejs2] doesn't because by now they mean the same thing. If Vue versions would coexist forever it might but they don't. At some point [vue.js] will be synonymous with [vuejs3] and it will make sense to merge those as well. Using your own example, you wouldn't want to see a separate question on how to iterate through an array for each ecmascript-version. Just like no one would need such an answer for ES1.

Comment: Because there will perpetually be projects that use Vue2, and that version-specific information will be difficult to find if we merge it with the main tag.

Comment: Just because Vue itself moves on to future versions doesn't mean that people stop using previous ones, especially major versions. The best way to categorize knowledge about past versions for future reference is by leaving the version tags intact.

Comment: Preserving the version differences is reasonable, but having `vue.js` forever keep referring to the *old, obsolete* version is probably a recipe for mistagging disaster. What do you think about using something along the lines of `vuejs1` for the old version, while `vuejs` refers to Vue in general, perhaps in combination with a version specific tag? Like `python` and `python-3.x`

Comment: @zcoop98 I agree if people were using Vue 1. But if you check the [vue.js]-tag you will find that no one is.

Comment: And this is why version tags are not useful, and version should be stated in the body of the question if it's relevant, not just because.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe I was unclear- as it is today, [[tag:vue.js]] refers to the library as a whole, *not* a specific version. Merging with [[tag:vuejs2]] would create exactly the situation you describe once Vue3 is commonplace, since the main tag will be combined with an "old, obsolete version".

Comment: @leonheess There are Vue.js v1 questions tagged with [[tag:vue.js]]. They don't have a tag of their own, which makes finding them exceedingly difficult. This same difficulty will eventually occur for v2 if we merge v2 into the main.

Comment: Added both of my above points to the answer, with a little more context on Vue versions.

Comment: @CertainPerformance To clarify, I'm agreeing with your proposal, I'm on the same page!

Comment: Exactly; like many other tags, e.g. `C#` and then `C#-1.2`,  `C#-2.0`, `C#-4.0`, `C#-4.0`, etc. Correctly retagging v1 Qs however might be challenging.

Answer (score 7):

The tag wiki already states that (my emphasis)

> Vue.js questions are highly version specific and should always be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3] **in addition to this tag.**

So that means that [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) is the general tag used for all Vue versions, and you should add an version specific tag if needed (or always).

So, we should not merge them, as this will cause issues when v3 becomes predominant.

What could be done (if needed) is add a [vuejs1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs1) tag for legacy questions.