# Dispute Tag synonym [Google-Calendar] -> [google-calendar-API]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

As per [How can I dispute a tag synonym?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253382/how-can-i-dispute-a-tag-synonym) I am coming here to dispute a synonym I have just run across.

Tag in question is [Google-Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-calendar/info) synonyms in question is google-calendar-API it can be seen here [Tag synonyms for google-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-calendar/synonyms)

[Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/) is a web application created by Google to display a user's calendar information.  The [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) lets you integrate your app with Google Calendar, creating new ways for you to engage your users.  These are two completely separate things.

There is a precedent for separating them as we currently have

- [youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube) and [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api)
- [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) and [google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api)
- [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) and [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) (not happy with this one but ok)
- [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) and [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api)
- [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) and [google-maps-api-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2)

There is definitely a problem because someone has created Google-Calendar-API3 in order to get past the incorrect synonym.  While the Google Calendar API is in fact in V3 we don't need the v3 as there is currently only one version of the Calendar API all others have been deprecated.   One could argue that we should have a main tag of [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api) and have [google-calendar-api3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api3) be the synonym of that.

The issue is that we need to tag API related questions to the application or use the strange api3 tag.  See question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43752776/1841839).

Side note: [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk)  actually has a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-drive-sdk/synonyms)  on it for Google-drive-API which is also technically incorrect as the [sdk](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) is for Android/iOS stuff and the API is a [rest API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) they are two different types of questions.   I have just learned to live with this one.

Side note 2: [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) has [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-spreadsheet/synonyms) for [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and [sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheets).  The correct term should be [Google Sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/) so the synonym is backwards

Comment: Can you ask a valid programming question about the goole calendar app that isn't about the API?

Comment: Probably not.   But that could also be said about the YouTube and Google drive tags.   Most of those questions i end up vote closing and sending over to super user.

Comment: Wasn't disputing that, but don't know enough about them from a programming perspective to know for sure

Comment: I follow any tag Google related for the last four years.  I have been developing with the APIs and the applications for five years.  Ask all the questions you like I am here to plead my case :o).   See if we can come to an agreement on this.   This is the first time i have tried to get a synonym removed happy to answer any questions needed.

Comment: Your 3rd bullet is not valid.  Google Drive is a synonym of Google Drive SDK.  You are also missing one as there is both [tag:google-sheets] and [tag:google-spreadsheet].  And there is [tag:google-maps-api-3] as well.

Comment: I agree Google-sheets and Google-spreadsheets are the same thing Google uses the first one.  Wasn't sure if i needed to go though all the tags.   I wouldn't mind cleaning them all up but lets do this one at a time.   Check my side note on Google-drive-sdk i suspect i was typing that as you were adding your comment.

Comment: A valid question about Google Calendar (or Sheets) that is not about the calendar API might be e.g. on using the Apps script calendar service.

Comment: Yeah but App script just uses the same API doesn't it if i recall correctly app script is just using the JS client library for an api.  I would just tag it both API and app-script.   But i see your point.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't have a problem with getting rid of Google-Calendar and the other non-API tags on the grounds that on topic questions would relate to the API. The non-API tags would probably have to be blacklisted to prevent them being recreated.

Comment: Some of them could be considered valid and should remain Google-analytics for example could pertain to the JavaScript snippet which is measurement protocol and not api

Comment: @DaImTo: A note: Off-topic (but otherwise excellent) non-programming questions about web applications (and not smartphone apps) like Google Calendar belong on [webapps.se], _not_ Super User.

Comment: I didn't know that one existed good to know

Comment: I'd say your examples should also be synonyms and this one should stay. There is nothing programming-related that is on Topic for SO which you could ask for Goofle Calendar.

Comment: In which case the tag should be Google-calender-api and Google-calender should be removed or become the synonym

Comment: Did we ever come to a conclusion on how to fix this?  The issue remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever possible, we should try to differentiate between products (which may or may not be on-topic here) and APIs for those products (which nearly *always* will be on-topic here).

So I went with [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api), with [google-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar) and [google-calendar-api3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api3) as synonyms.

Also renamed google-spreadsheet to google-sheets.

Please raise a separate discussion about the Drive tags; I know very little about them.

Comment: Be wary that too-broad-sounding tags attract off-topic questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/should-we-burninate-the-kali-linux-tag, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372576/lets-clean-up-postfix-mta