# Users doing Google first-level customer support

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, users, answer-quality

I have a slight issue with the behavior of a few users here. I won't link to them specifically, but they all have (*or had*) the same "About me" in their profile which says (*or used to say*): *Google Maps APIs Technical Support Ninja*.

It is unclear to me whether they are *official* Google Maps support employees or if these are self-attributed titles.

I have downvoted and/or flagged already so many of their answers for being *not an answer* or *very low quality* that I come to the point where I am asking myself what I should do (if anything) about it.

In many occasions, they use Stack Overflow to provide very basic [customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) answers like pointing people to the documentation (link only), explaining how billing works, how to open a bug in their issue tracker, etc. and most of the time, answering questions that should be closed (off-topic for whatever reason, duplicates, too broad, etc.).

- Should *we* do something about them?
- Or should I just keep flagging and/or downvoting their answers when I feel it is necessary?

I am not saying these users should be banned. Most of them provide some quality answers from time to time. I just feel they should refrain themselves from using Stack Overflow for first-level customer support.

As requested, here are a few examples of what I consider low-quality/first-level support answers.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447311
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947627
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62649268
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610013
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098858
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59082551
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51363485
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516437
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050296
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568354
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61925851
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61904986
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61451069

Comment: @MrUpsidown - well, somebody at Maps support team really [likes the idea of SO support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support). When editing Google APIs tag wiki, I was surprized to see a list of tags on the suppport page (which I think is bad practice - as it goes against the ["split API from the product"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374657/11407695) idea and creates extra curation burden). Probably nothing we can do apart from what you already do - a possible idea: keep posting updates, and someone on the team surely will notice the discussion once it gains traction.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this support page and the fact that Google pushes their users to get support here which I don't really have an issue with. I wish they would make it clearer though that they should come here for **technical/coding questions** only. I close-vote Google Maps related questions almost on a daily basis, from users who have questions about their billing account, their non-working API key, etc. and they often don't understand they don't get an answer because of that exact page. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: I also wish that if the users I mentioned in my question really are Google support employees, they would use SO with all due respect to the platform rules and not take it for their own support channel, providing information to head to the issue tracker or to contact the support team the proper way; that is, in a comment, and not in an answer (that's what they should do IMO).

Comment: @MrUpsidown - I don't have too, especially if staff participates as prominently as some. Just a bit worried that officially linking tags to issues could one day lead to disputes during cleanups / retags / etc. Re:clearer - well, they have a whole section, but something tells me that those who ask such questions rarely do read FAQs, help centers or even tag wikis prior to posting. Re:page - don't mind my links, I am sure you've seen this all - I always insert them so others have context where applicable. Re:employees - I guess this is an unofficial position, can't find anything public?

Comment: Seems like quite a few of your links have just been taken down.

Comment: Tangentially related: [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting)

Comment: Down voting these answers led me to receive a moderator warning message that my behavior was unacceptable. I thought their behavior was unacceptable, and actually it's mine. Anyone willing to close or delete this question, please go ahead.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - did you make many similar votes in a relatively short time span?

Comment: I asked some of the **questions** to be closed on SOCVR and someone noticed several answers were downvoted (by me) and raised a mod flag, which I suppose led to the message I received.